# Вывод min/max из генерируемого списка js

Tags: javascript

Есть код, он работает только когда указать статичные данные в var = mass[].
Но у меня значение генерируются  случайными числами и при этом сам масив выводит а от значение min/max - NaN

Как исправить?

```
var mass = [];
var min = mass[0];
var max = mass[0];

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    mass[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

}
for (j = 0; j < mass.length; j++) {
    max = Math.max(max, mass[j]);
    min = Math.min(min, mass[j]);

    if (max < mass[j]) {
        max = mass[j];
    }

}
console.log(mass, min, max);
```

Comment: чему по вашему равны `min`, `max` на первой итерацие?

Comment: тот же NaN только отображается столько раз сколько есть значений в масиве.

Comment: оооокей, чуть упрощу задачу, чему они равны до выполнения циклов? Почему они этому равны?

Comment: Да... дела! Не мучай уже)

Comment: равны первому значению из цыкла. По сути мы же не знаем какое значение min / max..

Comment: до выполнения первого `for` сколько значений у вас в массиве?

Comment: нет значений. если создавать по ходу переменные, то тоже не работает

Comment: Серьёзно ... перенеси просто инициализацию `min`, `max` под первый цикл ... Когда ты задаешь их так как ты их задаешь, они имеют значение `undefined`, ибо `mass[0]` не существует, так как массив ещё пуст. В итоге ты сравниваешь число с undefined, получая `NaN` ...

Comment: я только сделал так.. сенQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var mass = [];    
   for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        mass[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    }

    var min = mass[0];
    var max = mass[0];

    for (j = 0; j < mass.length; j++) {
        max = Math.max(max, mass[j]);
        min = Math.min(min, mass[j]);

        if (max < mass[j]) {
            max = mass[j];
        }

    }
    console.log(mass, min, max);
```

Comment: Задавать так переменные - плохой паттерн.

Comment: @MedvedevDev поправил. Просто суть была в другом.